# PyQt QVariant with dictionary

Tags: python, pyqt

If you execute this code in python:

```
from PyQt4 import uic, QtCore, QtGui
qvdict = QtCore.QVariant(dict(name='a'))
print qvdict.toPyObject()
qvtuple = QtCore.QVariant(('name','a'))
print qvtuple.toPyObject())
```

The result is:

```
{PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'name'): PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'a')}
('name', 'a')
```

As you can see keys and string values in qvdict are converted to QString but not for the qvtuble.

Is there a way to preserve the dictionary exactly as it was when initialysing the QVariant object when using toPyObject method?

I know I can do the conversion my-self by rebuilding the dictionary and converting each keys and string values, but shouldn't their be a way so Qt give me back the exactly same object?

If anybody knows why Qt is doing this conversion, I'd like understand why it's like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQt will try to convert to the corresponding C++ type if it can.

For a `dict`, this means a `QMap` - but only if *all* the keys are strings. Otherwise, it just wraps a reference to the original `dict` (i.e. there is no implicit copying).

For a `list`, the conversion is to a `QList`, but it isn't necessary that all the contained elements are also convertible.

For a `tuple`, there is no corresponding C++ type, and so no conversion is attempted (the `QVariant` will therefore just contain a wrapped reference).

This should immediately suggest a workaround to ensure that *any* python object is preserved when converting to and from a `QVariant`: simply wrap it in a `tuple`. However, a better long-term solution might be to avoid the use of `QString` and `QVariant` altogether. If you're using Python 2, this can be done using the [sip module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html) to [switch to the v2 API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html):

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

Alternatively, you can just use Python 3, where the v2 API is the default.